# My piece of code is trying to read a doc/ docx file. Call to the WordExtractor constructor is giving an error of ambiguity

Tags: java, apache-poi

I copied the code below from a website. It reads .doc/ .docx file in Java using the Apache POI package.

`WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(doc);` gives the following error: 
`reference to WordExtractor is ambiguous. Both constructor WordExtractor(POIFSFileSystem) in WordExtractor and WordExtractor(HWPFDocument) in WordExtractor match.`

Sorry for any silly mistakes, I am doing this .doc reading for the first time.
Thank You all ! :)

Code:

```
package testdeployment;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;


/**
 *
 * @author Aishwarya
 */
public class MsFileReader {
public static void readDocFile(String fileName) {

    try {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());

        HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fis);

        WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(doc);

        String[] paragraphs = we.getParagraphText();

        System.out.println("Total no of paragraph "+paragraphs.length);
        for (String para : paragraphs) {
            System.out.println(para.toString());
        }
        fis.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void readDocxFile(String fileName) {

    try {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());

        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(fis);

        List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = document.getParagraphs();

        System.out.println("Total no of paragraph "+paragraphs.size());
        for (XWPFParagraph para : paragraphs) {
            System.out.println(para.getText());
        }
        fis.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    readDocxFile("C:\\Test.docx");

    readDocFile("C:\\Test.doc");

}
```

}

Comment: `new WordExtractor((HWPFDocument)doc)` should do the trick.

Comment: @theV0ID : I did it. Same error.

Comment: You must be missing *something*. The class `HWPFDocument`  doesn't even support the `POIFSFileSystem` interface according to the class reference available online.

Comment: Thank you all for the help ! I figured out the problem. There were some missing imports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone with a similar problem can use the following jar files for the code above.

- `poi-3.11-20141221.jar`
- `poi-ooxml-3.11-20141221.jar`
- `poi-ooxml-schemas-3.11-20141221.jar`
- `poi-scratchpad-3.11-20141221.jar`
- `xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar`

  from: http://poi.apache.org/download.html
- `dom4j-1.6.jar` from: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/d/Downloaddom4j16jar.htm

Answer (score 4):

Hi this code is working you can write this one,

```
public static void readDocxFile(String fileName) {

    try {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        POIFSFileSystem fs = null;
        fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);
        readParagraphs(doc);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void readParagraphs(HWPFDocument doc) throws Exception{
        WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(doc);

        /**Get the total number of paragraphs**/
        String[] paragraphs = we.getParagraphText();
        System.out.println("Total Paragraphs: "+paragraphs.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {

            System.out.println("Length of paragraph "+(i +1)+": "+ paragraphs[i].length());
            System.out.println(paragraphs[i].toString());

        }

    }
```

Comment: Same error. Am i missing any package to be imported ??

Comment: @AishwaryaTiwari I used poi-3.11. Which one you are using.